# S-400 technology transfer to Turkey

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, military, turkey, technology

As far as I know, the Turkish proposal to purchase Patriot PAC-3 was refused because Turkey wanted a technology transfer, but the USA didn't want to.

**Am I correct?**

If I am correct, then what is going on with the Turkish S-400 deal with Russia regarding the same concept? Is Turkey getting a tech transfer from Russia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article from January 11, 2021](https://iz.ru/1110018/2021-01-11/turtciia-nazvala-uslovie-pokupki-vtorogo-komplekta-s-400), Turkey states that it will only purchase the second party of S-400s if the tech transfer will be included in the deal. [Apparently](https://iz.ru/1131928/2021-03-03/v-ankare-zaiavili-o-peregovorakh-s-rf-o-pokupke-vtorogo-polka-s-400), as of March 3rd, these talks are still underway, so no tech transfer was approved by Russia at that point, and I do not see any news on the matter.

So why buy S-400? Well, looking at [this article](https://www.defenceturkey.com/en/content/a-look-at-turkey-s-pac-3-iamds-procurement-activities-3332), it might be an attempt to driving down costs of offers. While Turkey states that it does not see S-400 and PAC-3 as competitors, the data on these systems suggest that their stated capabilities are similar, and the cost of Russian system seems to be significantly lower on per-unit basis than the American one. So even if Turkey won't get the tech it wants in the end, at least it will get more batteries for its money.